# What is the name of Python's root logger?

Tags: python, logging

I'm following a basic tutorial on logging in Python, https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html#a-simple-example, and following the steps in an iPython console. As described there, the default level of the root logger is `WARNING`:

```
In [1]: import logging

In [2]: logging.warning('Watch out!')
WARNING:root:Watch out!

In [3]: logging.info('I told you so')
```

I'd like to explicitly set the level of the root logger to `INFO`. I tried doing it using `name='root'`, but this has no apparent effect:

```
In [4]: logging.getLogger('root').setLevel(logging.INFO)

In [5]: logging.info('I told you so')
```

I am able to set the level of the root logger if I call `logging.getLogger()` without arguments:

```
In [6]: logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.INFO)

In [7]: logging.info('I told you so')
INFO:root:I told you so
```

I'm curious, though, why this didn't work the first time? It would seem that this should work since its `name` attribute is 'root':

```
In [12]: root_logger = logging.getLogger()

In [14]: root_logger.name
Out[14]: 'root'
```

In short, if I didn't want to rely on the default, what name would I pass to `logging.getLogger()` in order to get the root logger?

Comment: The root logger has a `name` attribute, but it's not stored in the dictionary with other loggers you define and thus isn't accessible by name via `getLogger()`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The root logger's name is `root`, but you can't access the root logger by name.

Inspecting [logging.py](https://bugs.python.org/file4410/logging.py) reveals this:

```
def __init__(self, root):
    """
    Initialize the manager with the root node of the logger hierarchy.
    """
    self.root = root
    self.disable = 0
    self.emittedNoHandlerWarning = 0
    self.loggerDict = {}
```

`root` is stored separately from `loggerDict`, which is where all named loggers go.

```
def getLogger(name=None):
    """
    Return a logger with the specified name, creating it if necessary.
    If no name is specified, return the root logger.
    """
    if name:
        return Logger.manager.getLogger(name)
    else:
        return root
```

You can follow the `manager.getLogger` internal function and find it cannot find `root`:

```
def getLogger(self, name):
        """
        Get a logger with the specified name (channel name), creating it
        if it doesn't yet exist. If a PlaceHolder existed for the specified
        name [i.e. the logger didn't exist but a child of it did], replace
        it with the created logger and fix up the parent/child references
        which pointed to the placeholder to now point to the logger.
        """
        rv = None
        _acquireLock()
        try:
            if self.loggerDict.has_key(name):
                rv = self.loggerDict[name]
                if isinstance(rv, PlaceHolder):
                    ph = rv
                    rv = _loggerClass(name)
                    rv.manager = self
                    self.loggerDict[name] = rv
                    self._fixupChildren(ph, rv)
                    self._fixupParents(rv)
            else:
                rv = _loggerClass(name)
                rv.manager = self
                self.loggerDict[name] = rv
                self._fixupParents(rv)
        finally:
            _releaseLock()
        return rv
```

Answer (score 3):

root logger is accessed by:

```
logging.getLogger('')
```

example code:

```py
logging.warning('Watch out!')
logging.getLogger('').setLevel(logging.INFO)
logging.info('I told you so')
```

output:

```
  WARNING:root:Watch out!
  INFO:root:I told you so
```

Comment: It is more commonly (your way *might* work) accessed as `logging.getLogger()`, as the OP is already aware...